# Contenteditable Editing Only Plain Text

Tags: html, button, contenteditable

I have a table that contains contenteditable=true cells.
I wish to insert a button into those cells but the problem is that I can backspace those buttons away and I don't want that too happen.
Here is what I am doing:

```
<table><tr>
<td contenteditable=true>Text Here
<button>Don't delete me!</button>
</td>
```

I don't want to create two spans inside the cell, one editable and one not, because I cant figure out how to make it fill the entire cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the button into another `<td>`.

```css
td {border: dashed 1px red}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">Text Here
      <td contenteditable="false"><button>Don't delete me!</button></td>
      <td contenteditable="true">After button Text Delete me
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest any elements inside an element with `contenteditable` unless you don't care about them being deleted. Nest a `contenteditable` element within the `<td>` or put the `<button>` outside of `<td>` and use `position:relative` or `transform:translate` over the `<td>`. This Snippet demonstrates three ways.
The second and third examples are fragile and can break easily, the first example is the best and most simplest.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.ghost {
  position: relative;
  right: 150%;
  top: 14px;
}
.extended {
  position: relative;
  right: 12%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  right: 170%;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.up {
  position: relative;
  right: 170%;
  z-index: 1;
}
button {
  display: block;
}
td {
  min-width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label contenteditable=true>Example 1</label>
      <button>Don't delete me!</button>
    </td>
    <td class='extended' contenteditable=true>
      Example 2
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class='ghost'>Don't delete me!</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='bg' contenteditable=true>Example 3</div>
      <button class='up'>Don't delete me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```